# How to set products as product options for some items

Tags: magento, product

I'd like to offer customers the chance to add accessories to the shopping cart as well has the product they are looking at. The best way to do this is as options, the problem is Magento cannot be configured to set options that are products, which when selected are added to the cart.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve.

I have a product, lets say it's a Laptop.

I also have other products like a carry bag, USB mouse and VGA cable.

On the Laptop product page I'd like to offer these accessories in the same way product options are offered.

How can this be done?

I'm looking into re-positioning the related products box so it sits near the add to cart button but it's fairly difficult and seems a lot for what I thought would be really straight forward.

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is already available in Magento - you need to create a 'Bundle Product'. In the 'associated products' tab while creating your bundle product you can add extras such as bags etc, as dropdown options or checkboxes.

Checkout this similar product on the Magento Demo store: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/computer.html - this is a bundle product. Remember that the main product (laptop) also needs to be created a simple product and associated to the bundle in the same way.

Comment: Yes bundled products do work but they are really there for customers who expect to build their products.

I'd like to keep it easy  to order  the main product (laptop) plus advertise accessories as well.

Another example would be:

A Mountain Bike with a water bottle and pump as optional extras.

Comment: With a bundle product can the customer look at each option for further information? @adam-moss

Comment: @Alex Howe Bundles don't have to look like you're building a product. Any extras can be optional, they're not 100% required (like the Peripherals section of the demo I linked to). The ability to see further information can definitely be coded into the bundle page, but it's not possible by default.

Comment: thanks for the further info. I've managed to call the related.phtml from the add to cart area to display the related product which I can easily manage, just need to alter the css to style it better.

If anyone wants to know how this has been done I can share.